# JQuery: Among selected elements, select nth element

Tags: jquery

Given HTML such as :

```
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <p class="selected">Hello Again</p>
  <div class="selected">And Again</div>
  <p>And One Last Time</p>
</div>
```

And JS such as :

```
$( "div" ).children( ".selected" )[0].css( "color", "blue" ); // this doesn't work
```

It doesn't grab the first selected element. **How to make it work ?**

Note: it's for a loop, so I will have access to a `var i`.

https://jsfiddle.net/kg20avn5/

Comment: Use `.eq` instead of the bracket notation.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/eq/ Looks good :)

Comment: `.selected` isn't a child of `p`; it's a sibling

Comment: corrected. See the fiddle for the source of the error

Comment: We shouldn't have to go to another site to see a [mcve]. Edit your question to put the code you need here.

Comment: Agree. Was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.eq`

```
$("div").children(".selected").eq(0).css("color", "blue");
```

or

```
$("div").children(".selected:eq(0)").css("color", "blue");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "div" ).children(".selected").first().css( "color", "blue" ); // this works
```

Comment: I made a typo in the question.

Comment: In the question, the 'Note' ask for a more flexible answer, `.eq()` will do. Richard also was faster. Yet thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Hugolpz, That's OK. But, I was faster with your first question. Then, you changed the question. However, I'm glad you found the answer. No matter whose do you accept :) . Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so when you use

```
.children( ".selected" )[0].css( "color", "blue" )
```

you're derfeferencing the jQuery object and getting the native DOM element. The problem with that is then you're trying to use a jQuery method (`.css()`) on it, which is why it fails.

To select the first match of something in jQuery you would typically use `.eq(0)`, `:eq(0)`, or `:first`

**Example 1**

```js
$( "div" ).children( ".selected:first" ).css( "color", "blue" );
```

```css
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  p { margin: 5px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <p class="selected">Hello Again</p>
  <div class="selected">And Again</div>
  <p>And One Last Time</p>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```js
$( "div" ).children( ".selected:eq(0)" ).css( "color", "blue" );
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  p { margin: 5px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <p class="selected">Hello Again</p>
  <div class="selected">And Again</div>
  <p>And One Last Time</p>
</div>
```

**Example 3**

```js
$( "div" ).children( ".selected" ).eq(0).css( "color", "blue" );
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  p { margin: 5px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <p class="selected">Hello Again</p>
  <div class="selected">And Again</div>
  <p>And One Last Time</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you can not add html tags within p tag. 
As a rule you can not use block elements within p tag such as "div" , "p" tags however you can only use inline elements like "span", "strong" etc..

if you try to use block elements within your p tag javascript or jquery would behave weirdly.

check your html code syntax you must be getting red line